# Building Spring MVC application using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to build a very simple Spring MVC application using Spring Boot. By now all my attempts have failed. Here is the configration:

WebConfig:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("newTestProject")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(WebConfig.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

WebAppInitializer:

```
@Configuration
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{WebConfig.class};
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>messagesAppHiber</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

There are no error messages in the console:

```
2017-03-15 21:25:49.631  INFO 1192 --- [           main] newTestProject.config.WebConfig          : Starting WebConfig on Rafale-2-ПК with PID 1192 (D:\TEMP\untitled\target\classes started by Rafale-2 in D:\TEMP\untitled)
2017-03-15 21:25:49.633  INFO 1192 --- [           main] newTestProject.config.WebConfig          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-03-15 21:25:49.702  INFO 1192 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1188e820: startup date [Wed Mar 15 21:25:49 EET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-03-15 21:25:51.122  INFO 1192 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-03-15 21:25:51.136  INFO 1192 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-03-15 21:25:51.137  INFO 1192 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
2017-03-15 21:25:51.248  INFO 1192 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-03-15 21:25:51.249  INFO 1192 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1549 ms
2017-03-15 21:25:51.393  INFO 1192 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-03-15 21:25:51.399  INFO 1192 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-15 21:25:51.399  INFO 1192 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-15 21:25:51.399  INFO 1192 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-15 21:25:51.399  INFO 1192 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-15 21:25:51.661  INFO 1192 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1188e820: startup date [Wed Mar 15 21:25:49 EET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-03-15 21:25:51.714  INFO 1192 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String newTestProject.controllers.IndexController.index()
2017-03-15 21:25:51.717  INFO 1192 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-03-15 21:25:51.717  INFO 1192 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-03-15 21:25:51.741  INFO 1192 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-03-15 21:25:51.741  INFO 1192 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-03-15 21:25:51.769  INFO 1192 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-03-15 21:25:51.941  INFO 1192 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-03-15 21:25:51.989  INFO 1192 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-03-15 21:25:51.992  INFO 1192 --- [           main] newTestProject.config.WebConfig          : Started WebConfig in 2.634 seconds (JVM running for 2.935)
2017-03-15 21:25:57.507  INFO 1192 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-03-15 21:25:57.507  INFO 1192 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-03-15 21:25:57.519  INFO 1192 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 12 ms
```

[image: structure]

The result should be index.jsp shown in my browser, but instead I get Whitelabel Error Page. What's wrong with this configuration?

Comment: Is there a reason you (1) are using war packaging and (2) are manually specifying a `@ComponentScan` scope?

Comment: war/jar - it makes no difference. The result is the same in both cases. With or without @ComponentScan the result is the same too. Whitelabel Error Page.

Comment: Use jar. What is the folder configuration? What do the startup logs look like? What are the packages on the classes?

Comment: You're getting an error message on the console. Post it.

Comment: There are no error messages in the console. See the log above (added)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Remove `WebAppInitializer` class - it is not needed since spring boot automatically configures it.

2) Remove `web.xml`. I don't know what you have there but it is not needed since you're using annotation configuration.

3) Enable the default servlet by overriding `configureDefaultServletHandling` in `WebConfig`.

```
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
        DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

4) Add the following maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

5) Run the project using maven

`$ mvn clean spring-boot:run`

PS: I don't know what you have in your jsp file. But this approach will work for sure if you use plain html. If you're using some `jstl` stuff there you have to add jstl dependency as well

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```